# Need good tutorial for TabActivity

Tags: android, tabactivity

I am working on a TabActivity.
I need to learn more detail about it.
There are tutorial regarding this. But all of them are brief.

I want DETAIL. So, if you know such site, give me the address.

---

Shaiful

Comment: When you have understand the way it works basically, you can start digging in the API. There is nothing more detailed about what you can do than the API.

Comment: Probably what @Shaiful means is when to use TabActivity and what are its pros/cons.

Comment: @CommonsWare : The word DETAIL refer to Everything about TabActivity. And I want to know, is it possible to calling another activity in a tabactivity. And how to switch between activity(In the same tab) keeping the tabwidget intact. And more detail about tabwidget design. And many many more. please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

When I was working on tabs I followed these tutorials
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1/
[http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-2/](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-%E2%80%93-part-2)